# beforeunload works only on page refresh, not on page leave

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I am using `react-admin` framework (3.2) and I am trying to fire the `beforeunload` event, when the user is navigating from the `Edit form` view. Lets say my pathname is `"feed/123"`. When the url changes in any way (user is navigating away from the edit form), the `beforeunload` should fire.
So far I have tried this code:

```
const FeedEdit = props => {
    const alertUser = (e) =>
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = '';
        console.log('fired'); //console.log is present on F5, not when leaving the page
    }

    useEffect(() =>
    {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', alertUser);
        return () => { window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', alertUser); };
    }, [])

    return <>
        <PageTitle type="edit" {...props} />
        <Edit {...props}>
          {/* other components */}
        </Edit>
    </>
};
```

However, this only fires the `beforeunload` event when refreshing the url. Any ideas how to fire the event when navigation away from the form?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yup, thats true, since the unload will trigger when you leave the page, but when you replace the url you are still in the same page with different content...

you can do that by adding a new hook to track location changes in component wrapper:

```
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Location changed', location);
  }, [location]);
```

Notes: you have a lot of options will help you in react routers, also you can build a custom hook to can re-use track code every where you want...(if you like to handle it for a specific routes component)

=================

### Update 1

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const useUnload = fn => {
  const cb = useRef(fn); // init with fn, so that type checkers won't assume that current might be undefined

  useEffect(() => {
    cb.current = fn;
  }, [fn]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const onUnload = cb.current;

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", onUnload);
    window.addEventListener("unload", onUnload);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", onUnload);
      window.removeEventListener("unload", onUnload);
    }
  }, []);
};

export default useUnload;
```

This is a custom hook is used to handling unload page, we can use it just via call it inside needed component like this:

```
  // When Un-load event is trigger then trigger dis-counect and remove local track
  const unload = useCallback(() => {
....
  }, []);

  // Add event lisiner to trigger before unload
  useUnload(unload);
```

=================

### Update 2

For history listener you can use `history.listen`, for example:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    history.listen((loc, action) => {
      if(action === "POP"){// POP or PUSH
        window.location.reload();
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Well, if the event would fire when I'm leaving the page it would be okay too. But even then, the event is not fired.

Comment: You need to keep unload event Listerine, I will add an example for it too... now to answer, so the unload will trigger when leave the page and location will trigger when you replace url...

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution still doesnt fire the event on page leave

Comment: mm, This code copy from a real project, I think we need to do some trace, can you put a console log in unload function and check if its print any thing? also make sure the action is needed to execute not a promises since the window will leave before you execute it...

Comment: It does fire when refreshing the page. However, when I leave the page (goBack, goForward, different url) it doesnt fire. I just checked by console.logging

Comment: Yes that correct, its work...unload will work on leave only, but location must be work when change path...but if you need the action of froward and back this is another event...I will added it too...

Comment: Well it shouldn't be correct if it dosn't fire on simple page leave right?

Comment: IF its normal page not a one page style the unload will work in all cases, but if its single page like react the unload will work only before page is distroy, and push url to another pages will just trigger location change via url or history listener when try to push or pop pages